# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7, nonblocking, readfile

After research I found a solution to read a file without locking. But I can not decode received buffer from descriptor in the string / chars. How to do this? Or is there another option to read the file without blocking, and not working with bytes?

```
  filename = '/var/log/auth.log'
    fopen = os.open(filename, os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_RDONLY)
    while True:
        data = os.read(fopen, 1024)
        if len(data) > 0:
            #logger just for example in code is another function
            logger.info('DATA:   ',data)
            #print data
```

I receive error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Use `logger.info('DATA:  %s',data)`. Or just `print data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a value `data` [to be formatted into](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) the message, but your message doesn't contain a field for this to be substituted.  It follows the [printf-style string formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) by default.

```
logger.info('DATA: %s', data)
```